# Why isn't this multithreaded code faster?

Tags: java, multithreading, performance

This is my java code. Before, it calls `BatchGenerateResult` sequentially which is a lengthy process, but I want to try some multithreading and have each one of them run at the same time. However when I test it, the new time is the same as the old time. I expected the new time to be faster. Does anyone know whats wrong?

```
public class PlutoMake {

  public static String classDir;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException, IOException,
      InterruptedException {

    // determine path to the class file, I will use it as current directory
    String classDirFile = PlutoMake.class.getResource("PlutoMake.class")
        .getPath();
    classDir = classDirFile.substring(0, classDirFile.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);

    // get the input arguments
    final String logoPath;
    final String filename;
    if (args.length < 2) {
      logoPath = classDir + "tests/android.png";
      filename = "result.png";
    } else {
      logoPath = args[0];
      filename = args[1];
    }

    // make sure the logo image exists
    File logofile = new File(logoPath);
    if (!logofile.exists() || logofile.isDirectory()) {
      System.exit(1);
    }

    // get the master.js file
    String text = readFile(classDir + "master.js");
    JSONArray files = new JSONArray(text);

    ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    // loop through all active templates
    int len = files.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 1) {
      final JSONObject template = files.getJSONObject(i);
      if (template.getBoolean("active")) {
        es.execute(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            try {
              BatchGenerateResult(logoPath, template.getString("template"),
                  template.getString("mapping"),
                  template.getString("metadata"), template.getString("result")
                      + filename, template.getString("filter"),
                  template.getString("mask"), template.getInt("x"),
                  template.getInt("y"), template.getInt("w"),
                  template.getInt("h"));
            } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
          }
        });
      }
    }

    es.shutdown();
    boolean finshed = es.awaitTermination(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
  }

  private static void BatchGenerateResult(String logoPath, String templatePath,
      String mappingPath, String metadataPath, String resultPath,
      String filter, String maskPath, int x, int y, int w, int h)
      throws IOException, JSONException {
    ColorFilter filterobj = null;
    if (filter.equals("none")) {
      filterobj = new NoFilter();
    } else if (filter.equals("darken")) {
      filterobj = new Darken();
    } else if (filter.equals("vividlight")) {
      filterobj = new VividLight();
    } else {
      System.exit(1);
    }

    String text = readFile(classDir + metadataPath);
    JSONObject metadata = new JSONObject(text);

    Map<Point, Point> mapping = MyJSON.ReadMapping(classDir + mappingPath);

    BufferedImage warpedimage = Exporter.GenerateWarpedLogo(logoPath, maskPath,
        mapping, metadata.getInt("width"), metadata.getInt("height"));
    // ImageIO.write(warpedimage, "png", new FileOutputStream(classDir +
    // "warpedlogo.png"));

    Exporter.StampLogo(templatePath, resultPath, x, y, w, h, warpedimage,
        filterobj);

    warpedimage.flush();
  }

  private static String readFile(String path) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(path);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    byte[] data = new byte[(int) file.length()];
    fis.read(data);
    fis.close();
    String text = new String(data, "UTF-8");
    return text;
  }
}
```

Comment: How many CPU cores your machine has? Try `System.out.println(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());` What it prints?

Comment: 2 cpus (4 threads, intel i3 generation 1)

Comment: @sneaky, try `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());` and check the performance now. Also how many files you have? What is the value of `len` variable?

Comment: May be you have synchronized methods inside MyJSON, Exporter classes?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, for all practical purposes the following code should be the only one which can improve performance by using multithreading.

```
BufferedImage warpedimage = Exporter.GenerateWarpedLogo(logoPath, maskPath,
    mapping, metadata.getInt("width"), metadata.getInt("height"));
// ImageIO.write(warpedimage, "png", new FileOutputStream(classDir +
// "warpedlogo.png"));

Exporter.StampLogo(templatePath, resultPath, x, y, w, h, warpedimage,
    filterobj);
```

The rest of it major IO - I doubt how much performance improvement you can achieve there.

Do a profile and check how long each one of the methods is executing. Depending on that you should be able to understand.

Answer (score -1):

Hi sorry not able add to comment part as just joined..

would suggest to first go for dummy method any check whether it works at your end then add your business logic... 
if the sample works then you might need to check your "template" class
here's the sample.. check the timestamp

```
 package example;

    import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
    import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

    public class ExecutorStaticExample {


        public static void main(String[] args){
            ExecutorService  ex = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
            for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
                    ex.execute(new Runnable(){

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            helloStatic();
                            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());

                        }

                    });
            }
        }

        static void helloStatic(){
            System.out.println("hello form static");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: This example is not relevant to this code. If you answer a few questions that you do know how to answer, you will be able to comment on this question.

Comment: @durron.. Isn't it a basic rule to check the basic functionality and then to add business logic?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, though. Debugging tips are not an answer.